# Adding more or Less +/-

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to set up this code which works to display more or less of everything within the panel_menu to display + or - text next to the Menu button but I don't get how to make that happen in jQuery. The examples I've seen are dissimilar to what I have here.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#toggle_menu").click(function(){
     $("#panel_menu").slideToggle(0);
    });
  });
</script>

<style>
  h3 { padding: 5px; cursor: pointer; margin: 0px; }
  h3:hover { color: #ff0000; background: #eee; }
  #toggle,#toggle_menu { padding: 5px; }
  #panel_menu { margin: 0px; display:none; padding: 5px; }
</style>

<h3 id="toggle_menu">Menu </h3>
<div id="panel_menu">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
```

As is clicking on "Menu" exposes or hides the text correctly. How do you add a function to make it show +/- or something similar as more/less to clue the visitor?

Comment: There in no 'function' specifically. Add the +/- first...however you want...then figure out a function to change it.

Comment: You add an element holding the plus sign, then just toggle it, like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/vmeL71jr/**

Comment: That is brilliant @adeneo 2. Much better than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve this is to initialize "Menu" to "+ Menu" as follows:

```
<h3 id="toggle_menu">+ Menu </h3>

...

$(document).ready(function() {
  var tm =   $("#toggle_menu");
  tm.on('click',
    function () {
        $("#panel_menu").slideToggle(0);
        if(tm.text() == '- Menu') tm.text('+ Menu')
        else tm.text('- Menu');
    }
  );
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5x9obbm1/2/)

Comment: That's perfect. The real-life situation is much more robust, but I tested this and it will work marvelously. Thx.

Comment: Happy to hear that. I understand you are new to SO, but it is customary to accept the most helpful answers.